# React is not defined in Codesandbox, working fine locally

Tags: reactjs, codesandbox

Just wanted to host some sample code on Codesandbox, but this code in `MyTable.tsx`

```
import { FC, useState } from "react";

interface Row {
  id: number;
  content: string;
}

interface Props {
  initialRows: Row[];
}

export const MyTable: FC<Props> = function ({ initialRows }) {
  const [rows, setRows] = useState(initialRows);

  return (
    <table>
      <tbody>
        {rows.map((row, index) => (
          <tr key={`id${row.id}`}>
            <td>{row.content}</td>
            <td>
              <button
                type="button"
                onClick={() => {
                  const newRows = [...rows];
                  newRows.splice(index, 1);
                  setRows(newRows);
                }}
              >
                remove
              </button>
            </td>
          </tr>
        ))}
      </tbody>
    </table>
  );
};
```

ends up with *React is not defined*
[image]

That code works fine locally in VSCode and I can't figure out what the issue is. Full Codesanbox at https://codesandbox.io/s/delete-via-index-ctpes, the relevant file is `src/MyTable.tsx`. Would be glad about any hint, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add to the header:

```
import React, { FC, useState } from "react";
```

Comment: works fine, thank you :-) Any idea why I didn't need it locally?

Comment: You're welcome! It's bc the "tags" are transpiled to js code, and it is using the React reference. I don't know why it was working locally.

Comment: thank you, I understand that, but shouldn't my local build do the same, but there I don't need to import `React`?

Comment: Yeah... The reason to me it is unknown, but i always fixed this thing like this.

Comment: Have a look at https://reactjs.org/blog/2020/09/22/introducing-the-new-jsx-transform.html. You probably enabled new JSX transform locally while codesandbox does not support it eventually. Just guessing.